# Requiring luasnip to neovim causes errors

Tags: lua, neovim, snipmate

I am trying to use [luasnip](https://github.com/L3MON4D3/LuaSnipv).

The configuration I am using is [AstroNvim](https://github.com/AstroNvim/AstroNvim).
The modifications I made to this configuration are :

1. `require("luasnip.loaders.from_snipmate").lazy_load()` at the end of `init.lua`
2. Made a directory `snippets` in the same directory of `init.lua`, and added some basic snipmate styled snippets inside.

Commands Like `:LuaSnipListAvailable` works well, and snippets from `friendly-snippets` works well too.

However the following error message pops up when opening neovim.

```
Error detected while processing /Users/myusername/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ...m/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim/lua/packer/load.lua:171: Vim(echomsg):E121: Undefined variable: Error
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'cmd'
        ...m/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim/lua/packer/load.lua:171: in function <...m/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim/lua/packer/load.lua:16
7>
        /Users/myusername/.local/share/nvim/packer_compiled.lua:496: in function </Users/myusername/.local/share/nvim/packer_compiled.lua:485>
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /Users/myusername/.config/nvim/init.lua:23: in main chunk
```

I tried other methods of adding snippets, but any sort of `require("luasnip")` seems to break all.